# Nginx upstream name in log format

Tags: nginx, logging

Is there a way to use the *upstream name* in the nginx log format instead of the specific *upstream node* host/ip address used for handling a request ?

`$upstream_addr` is the variable to use for the specific node, and will give the name of the group when no functioning nodes are present. I want to *always* log the name of the upstream group itself, though.

I can't find anything about it in the official documentation, but perhaps there's an undocumented variable, compile option or module that makes it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried `$proxy_host`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`$proxy_host`](http://nginx.org/r/$proxy_host) variable. It contains host name specified in `proxy_pass` directive. In your case it's exactly upstream name.

Comment: I've found that `$proxy_host` is empty when no functioning nodes are present, so resorted to logging both `$proxy_host` _and_ `$upstream_addr`, and using the latter if the former is empty.

Comment: Just in case you’re wondering what other variables are there, here the list in the cods: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables